# Angular2 : Can't refresh when deploying on sub-folder

Tags: angular, apache, deployment, angular-cli

I'm trying to deploy my Angular2 application on my apache2 server. I'm not deploying into into the root but into a subfolder : /var/www/html/demo/tppj/

I built my application using this command:

```
ng build --base-href="/demo/tppj/"
```

It work perfectly when accessing the url mydomain/demo/tppj/ but if I refresh my page I get some code from the index located at /var/www/html/.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a server issue, which I'm not familiarized with. However, it seems that using hash to navigate could solve this problem.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you know --deploy-url ?

`--deploy-url "/demo/tppj/"` does add /demo/tppj/ before all *.budled.js files and assets referenced in css, but not for images referenced in html.

These links may help you.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1080

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4517

https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-pro-angular/issues/204

Thanks.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)